# How to discard old builds in Jenkins, based on their completion status?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job set up to poll for a change in a git repository every 10 minutes. If it doesn't find one (99/100 times, this is what happens) it aborts the build early and marks it as UNSTABLE . If it finds a change, it goes through with it and marks it as SUCCESS, storing its artifacts. I know I can use a plugin to discard old builds, but it only allows for these options:
[image: Jenkins parameters]
As you can see, there is no option to filter by completion status.

Ideally, I want to discard all but the latest UNSTABLE build and keep all SUCCESS or FAILED builds and their artifacts. If this is not possible, simply discarding *all* UNSTABLE builds would also work.

Note: I am using a declarative Pipeline

Comment: Which project are you using is it pipeline or freestyle project? If Pipeline, Is it a declarative pipeline or scripted one?

Comment: @HussainK Sorry, forgot to include that. It is a declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to discard builds programmatically. Get your job object with
 `def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem("JobName")` 
 Since you are using declarative pipeline, `job` is of type `WorkflowJob` [1] and you can get all its builds with 
`job.getBuilds()`. Now you can check the result of each build (`WorkflowRun` objects [2]) and decide if you want to delete it or not. Something like follows should work

```
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem("JobName")
job.getBuilds().each { 
  if(it.result.toString() == "UNSTABLE") {
    it.delete()
    job.save()
  }
}
```

You could create a new job that executes the code above and is triggered after `YourJob` has been built.

[1] https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.html 
[2] https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.html

Comment: Could this code snippet also be included in the `post { always { } }` of my Jenkinsfile, or even better the `post { unstable { } }` in order to avoid the `if` statement?

Comment: I haven't tried it. I am not sure if it is good idea, since it would mean, the build is still running (`UNSTABLE`) and is trying to delete itself.